# Improving Formatting For Math Assignment

Tags: formatting

I am fairly new to using LaTeX to typeset my math homework and I am having some troubles just doing some basic formatting. Ideally what I would like to have is the problem statement, in this case it would be A) in line with "Problem 1" and then work on the problem below it. That way my TA would be able to zip through the assignment quickly to distinguish which questions need to be marked (he marks them randomly for everybody). If there are any suggestions on how I could make this adjustment for better presentation, that would be welcomed.

```
\documentclass[fleqn, 12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{gensymb} % 
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb} 
\usepackage{stmaryrd}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}


 
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Problem 1}
\begin{equation*}
    \text{A)} \quad \int{\frac{\cos t}{(1 + \sin t)^{\frac{1}{2}} } \, dx}
\end{equation*}

\quad Let $ u = 1 + \sin t$ and $ \frac{\, du}{\, dt} = \cos t $ and, by substitution, we get:
\begin{equation}
    \int{ \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}} \, du} = 2\sqrt{u} + C
\end{equation}

\section*{Problem 2}

\section*{Problem 3}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you are not using table of contents, why not try `{\large\bfseries Problem 1}` and place the question afterwards?

Comment: Right now, it's not clear why you have both "Problem 1" and "A)". What does "A)" denote? Is it a start of a numbered list? Please clarify.

Comment: Problem One might have a class of problems, for example, solving integrals. Problem two might have a different class, like solving addition problems. So you could have Problem 1, but then part A, B, C, D, etc... then Problem 2 part A, B, C, etc. Does that clarify ?